# Forward AWT DnD Event to SWT

Tags: java, outlook, drag-and-drop, awt, swt

is there any way to process an AWT DnD via SWT.

Why do I ask such a question. The reason is quite simple. I want to make possible that our Java application is able to understand DnD events from MS Outlook, so that when User X drags an email from outlook and drops it on our application then our application should receive the .msg-file.

So, unluckely I  cannot simply use any library like Apache POI, due to some SAP policies. I can only use SWT for this job or I do some jni hacking.
Now you might think "hey you have SWT, then use it", yeah our GUI is completely written in Swing so...

I thought I could convert an AWT Transferable object to an SWT TransferData object, but it seams that I can't so that. The second thing I thought off is to forward the DnD event from AWT to SWT, but it seams to me that I have the same conversion problem here, too.

Does anybody know how to forward an AWT DnD event to SWT???
All my resarches are leading me to dead ends. Maybe I am asking google the wrong questions.

Or is such a thing not possible and I have to do some jni hacking??

Comment: So you're saying your application is a Swing app, so why use SWT at all?

Comment: We use SWT because we have one Component that has to use ActiveX.